# Javascript recursive generator/iterator class using [Symbol.iterator] iterable protocol without next()

Tags: javascript

The recursive generator/iterator `class IteratorClass{}` below works, but unsure about my implementation. I've found a binary tree and recursive generator/iterator examples but no documentation or examples to support my approach below, and I'm wondering if I need to do something differently. I've tested both sync and async, and it seems to work fine. Still, I'm not implementing `next()` function and wonder if I'm doing something wrong because most examples I've seen implement the generator next()`.

```js
   
class IteratorClass {
  constructor(routes, depth = 0) {
    this._routes = routes;
    this._depth = depth += 1
  }

  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (const [key, route] of this._routes.entries()) {

      route.depth = this._depth

      if (Array.isArray(route.children) && route.children.length) {
        yield* new IteratorClass(route.children, this._depth)
      }

      yield `ROUTE NAME: ${route.name} : ROUTE DEPTH: ${route.depth}`
    }
  }
}

const data = [{
    key: 1,
    path: '/users',
    name: 'users',
    children: [{
        key: 2,
        path: '/users/roles',
        name: 'roles'
      },
      {
        key: 3,
        path: '/users/permissions',
        name: 'permissions'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 4,
    path: '/projects',
    name: 'projects',
    children: [{
      key: 5,
      path: '/projects/milestones',
      name: 'milestones',
      children: [{
        key: 6,
        path: '/projects/milestones/tasks',
        name: 'tasks'
      }]
    }]
  }
]

/** instantiated  IteratorClass */
const syncGenerator = new IteratorClass(data)


for (const route of syncGenerator) {
  console.log('Yield route  : ', route)
}
```

Comment: This code is hard to read: you have named something an `iterator` that is not an iterator and `type` that is not a type.

Comment: You don't *have* to implement `next()`: a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) function returns an object that has `next`.

Comment: @trincot thanks adjusted based on feedback

Comment: You still have `type` in there... Also, the second code block has more closing braces than opening. It would be better that you build code that you can run without errors, and then copy/paste it without any change into one code block in your question.

Comment: @trincot sorry should have just done this in the first place. I think have the answer, but here is a code snippet to demonstrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `next()` when you loop through the iterObject in `for...of` and `Object.entries( ... )`. If you are looking for documentation you can see the following:

**[Iteration Protocols | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)**

`next()`

A function that accepts zero or one argument and returns an object conforming to the `IteratorResult` interface (see below). If a non-object value gets returned (such as `false` or `undefined`) when a built-in language feature (such as `for...of`) is using the iterator, a [`TypeError`](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) (`"iterator.next() returned a non-object value"`) will be thrown.

**[Generator | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator)**

```js
function* generator() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

const gen = generator(); // "Generator { }"

console.log(gen.next().value); // 1
console.log(gen.next().value); // 2
console.log(gen.next().value); // 3
```

**[Yield* | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*)**

The `yield*` expression iterates over the operand and yields each value returned by it. It delegates iteration of the current generator to an underlying iterator — which we will refer to as "generator" and "iterator", respectively. `yield*` first gets the iterator from the operand by calling the latter's `@@iterator` method. Then, each time the `next()` method of the generator is called, `yield*` calls the iterator's `next()` method, passing the argument received by the generator's `next()` method (always `undefined` for the first call), and yielding the same result object as what's returned from the iterator's `next()` method. If the iterator result has `done: true`, then the `yield*` expression stops executing and returns the `value` of that result.

**[Yield | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield)**

A `yield` expression. In this case, the generator pauses, and the `next()` method return an `iterator result` object with two properties: `value` and `done`. The `value` property is the value of the expression after the `yield` operator, and `done` is `false`, indicating that the generator function has not fully completed.

Comment: The first phrase is false. `next` is not implemented by doing a `for..of` loop.

Comment: OK, poor choice of words. I will update it to `using` instead of `implementing`.

Comment: @svarlitskiy thanks for the help. FWIW, Loaded a code snippet.